# UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag when nothing to scroll doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to hide the keyboard with swipe gesture, in iOS 7 i know there is `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag` but this seems to work only when there is something to scroll, instead when the row result of the search are under the UIKeyboard but there are not enough row to scroll the view this `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag` is not working, because there is nothing to scroll, how i can dismiss the keyboard with a swipe gesture also when there is nothing to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(hideKeyBoard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

And the method:

```
-(void)hideKeyBoard {

[textViewOrTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most elegant code wise, and the nicest feel in use, is to always set

```
 self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

when using UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag.

That way you can always drag vertically against a bounce, so the issue doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that will help (at least it works for me).

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: if there is nothing to scroll, that method is not called

Comment: Call [myTextField resignFirstResponder]; in method, you want keyboard to dismiss (such as swipe gesture).